# SQL - Counting the number of users

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, mysql-workbench

I have written an sql code that return the number of cars per user.

```
SELECT count(car_name), id
FROM cars
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE("2013-01-01") AND DATE("2016-12-31")
GROUP BY 2
HAVING id > 2
```

The purpose of this code is to count the number of users within a specific time frame who have had at least 2 cars. However. the code above returns the following table

```
f0_ -- id
2  -- abdjdi23
3 --- jfhdfi123
2 ---- djndf33
```

But instead of this table, I just need it to return how many of the users have at least 2 cars or more. What should add to this code to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT count(*), id
      FROM cars
      WHERE date BETWEEN DATE('2013-01-01') AND DATE('2016-12-31')
      GROUP BY 2
      HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) x
```